# QGIS Semi-automatic classification plugin install error on OS X 10.10: matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification, osx

I have tried repeatedly to install the QGIS Semi-automatic classification plugin via both (1) `Plugins > Install & Manage Plugins` and (2) manually based on other comments I found here, but I can't get it to work. I continue to get the error:

```
The plugin is broken. Python said:
No module named matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg
```

I have checked and have installed matplotlib, GDAL, scipy, numpy via macports (QGIS was installed via macports as well, but I have uninstalled, reinstalled, and rebooted a couple of times at this point).

I am not sure how else to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib has many [backends](http://matplotlib.org/api/index_backend_api.html)

In my Mac OS X matplotlib (1.4.2) installation, using the pure Python script in [List of all available matplotlib backends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920412) the result is:

```
 print backends
 ['agg', 'cairo', 'cocoaagg', 'gdk', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'gtk3agg', 'gtk3cairo', 'gtkagg', 'gtkcairo', 'macosx', 'mixed', 'nbagg', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'qt4', 'qt4agg', 'qt5', 'qt5agg', 'svg', 'template', 'tkagg', 'webagg', 'webagg_core', 'wx', 'wxagg']
```

As you can see, there is a 'qt4agg' backend

As I use the default Apple Python, the backends files are in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.2/matplotlib/backends

[image]

So your matplotlib is not correctly installed or you PYTHONPATH is not correct. Look at
[Macports Ticket: py27-matplotlib say py27-pyqt4 not installed when using qt-backend](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31466)

But why use MacPorts ? There are other solutions available, more reliable, [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) or [Homebrew](http://blog.burhum.com/post/36080548777/getting-qgis-working-on-homebrew), look at [QGIS python location problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56970/qgis-python-location-problem)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful thank you! It did appear that there was a simple inconsistency between where Mac Ports installed python and what backends were identified. I ensured that python27 was the active python and then copied: `cp /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc ~/.matplotlib/` and uncommented the line: `backend.qt4 : PyQt4` in the matplotlib file.

Comment: I default to using MacPorts because I have other dependencies already utilizing installation paths from MacPorts. In my experience, when you install Homebrew and start using it for additional installs, many conflicts can arise.